# The proof of $F_{X|A}(-\infty) = 0$ and $F_{X|A}(\infty) = 1$

Tags: proof-verification, probability-distributions

How to prove this cumulative  distribution function ?

$F_{X|A}(-\infty) = 0$ and $F_{X|A}(\infty) = 1$ ,

What does $F_{X|A}(-\infty)$ mean?Is it the same as $F_{X|A}(X=-\infty|A=-\infty)$?I have no idea how to begin proving this.

Comment: A decent start would be to explain what $A$, $X$ are and how is $F_{X|A}$ defined.

Comment: $F(-\infty) = 0$ and $F(\infty) = 1$ is true for any c.d.f. (If $F$ is the c.d.f. of a random variable $X$, then notice that $F(-\infty) = \mathsf{P}[X \leq -\infty]$ and $F(\infty) = \mathsf{P}[X \leq \infty]$. Can you proceed from here?) As for the second question, you should begin by clarifying all the contexts as pointed out by other users. Is $A$ an event or a random variable? How does your textbook/literature define $F_{X\mid A}$? Etc. Knowing what and why  you don't know is a good way of knowing something.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is $F_{X|A} (-\infty)$ stands for $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac {P\{X \leq x, A\}} {P(A)} $. The events $\{X \leq x, A\}$ decrease to the empty set as $x$ decreases to $-\infty$ so their probabilities $\to 0$. Similarly, $\{X \leq x, A\}$ increase to $A$ as $x$ increases to $\infty$ so the probability $\to P(A)$. Now divide by $P(A)$.